# Hash table collision detected solution

Tags: vb.net, linked-list, hashtable, collision-detection

I am trying to find how to deal with collision detection with `HashTable`.

My hashing algorithm is bad and results in many collisions, I am working on a better algorithm: `HashKey = (Mid(HashKey, 1, 3) * Mid(HashKey, 1, 3) Mod 11)`

I am saving my structure `Stock`:

```
    <Serializable()>
Public Structure Stock
    'Create a structure for the hash table stock file
    <VBFixedString(10)> Public Barcode As String
    <VBFixedString(20)> Public Category As String
    <VBFixedString(20)> Public Title As String
    <VBFixedString(20)> Public Description As String
    <VBFixedString(4)> Public Quantity As Integer
    <VBFixedString(8)> Public RRP As Double
    <VBFixedString(8)> Public Cost As Double
End Structure
```

I am currently detecting collisions by means of:

```
If HashTable(HashKey) = "" Then
...
SaveStock
End If
```

Is this a reliable way of checking? If a collision is detected, how do I solve for VB.net. Do I have to implement my own linked list or does the Hashtable type have a property that deals with it?

Comment: You should use generic collections, not HashTable.

Comment: HashTable & Dictionary use unique keys.

Comment: that code screams `use a class`.  I bet if you added a product code (perhaps a version of BarCode), that would work as a Dictionary key

Comment: Well I am afraid for my coursework I am forced to use a HashTable to match the specification, but thank you for the constructive comment. @SLaks

Comment: As I said, I am forced to use a HashTable as oppose to a dictionary (although I agree with you!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse keys and hash codes! A key must be unique and identifies an object. The hash code is computed from the key when using hash tables. The `HashTable` does this by calling the `GetHashCode` method of the key.

The `HashTable` allows you to store and find objects by a key. Therefore you must use a known value as key. For instance the bar code which should be unique.

```
Dim stockTable As HashTable = New HashTable()
stockTable.Add(stock.Barcode, stock)
```

The `Item` property returns `Nothing` if an item with a given key is not found. Don't define `Stock` as structure define it as a class.

```
Dim stock As Stock = DirectCast(stockTable(someBarCode), Stock)
If stock Is Nothing Then
    ' No item found with this key
Else
    ' Success!
End If
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I set the hashcode though and where do I use `GetHashCode`?

Comment: Every class and struct inherits `GetHashCode` from `object` and is free to override it or not. All standard system types like `string`, `int` and so on override it and provide a suitable implementation. If you implement your own type you can do it as well. But you don't need to call it anywhere. The `HashTable` calls it internally on the key value. All you have to do is to supply a key value like the barcode, a product number or stock ID etc.

Answer (score 0):

Both HashTable and Dictionary deal with hash collisions for you. You'll get a lookup performance degredation, but as long as the key is unique (even if the hash of the key is not) you don't need to do anything. The containers will handle storage for you.

You still want to reduce hash collisions if you can for performance reasons; at worst case (all the keys hash the same) then it becomes a linear search through every key for a lookup.

Comment: What would the syntax be for this? How does the program know the unique key when searching? @ChrisTavares

Comment: Just do `hashTable(key) = value`. Everything else is handled automatically for you. It's up to you to determine what the key is based on your data of course.